# Why is $P^{ed} \bmod N = P^{1} \bmod N$ if $e$ and $d$ are modular inverses of $\phi(N)$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $d$ be the inverse of $e \bmod \phi(N)$.

Therefore,

$de \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)} $

$d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\phi(N)} $

In RSA encryption, we can decrypt messages because
$P^{ed} \bmod N = P^{1} \bmod N$

I don't understand why $P^{ed} \bmod N = P^{1} \bmod N$ if $e$ and $d$ are modular inverses of $\phi(N)$. What property is this?

Comment: Because $a^{\phi(N)}=1$ modulo $N$ by Euler, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789763/proof-if-textgcda-n-1-then-a-phin-1-is-divisible-by-n), for example.

Comment: I still don't understand because $ed \neq \phi(N)$

Comment: Note 1 raised to any power is 1 .